# Update Claim Value in token before sending it to WebApi in Authorization Header

Tags: .net-core, access-token, bearer-token, claims

I am getting country value using radio buttons from UI and then setting country in session,
In my project on each controller GetAccessToken method is calling,
in GetAccessToken Aquiring token using ADAL.NET and returning accessToken from GetAccessToken method to each controller.

now I want to update ctry claim in token with selectCountry value that is comes form UI before
returning accessToken to controller.

how can we aquire a new token with ctry updated value in url Parameters using our original token that is came from Api. Using ADAL.NET not MSAL.NET in .net core 2.1

I tried in MSAL.NET but my application is using ADAL.NET

`var _clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(App.ClientId) .WithDefaultRedirectUri() .WithAuthority(authority) .WithClientCapabilities(new [] {"cp1"}) .Build();` 
More details for what result I am Expecting review this link:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/claims-challenge?tabs=dotnet]

Thank you all, and if is there any better approach to achieve above result please let me know.

I'm Using Azure Ad to authenticate User.